# How to I disable clicking on jquery tablesorter header

Tags: tablesorter

I have a requirement where I need to display a table presorted on page load. I don't want the user to be able to re-sort the same. I have used tablesorter plugin to achieve the sorting ..but I am facing issues while  trying to disable sorting on header clicks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), set the sorter to false ([demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html))

In versions 2.3+, columns can be disabled using any of the following methods (they all do the same thing), in order of priority:

- jQuery data `data-sorter="false"`
- metadata `class="{ sorter: false }"`. This requires the metadata plugin.
- headers option `headers : { 0 : { sorter: false } }`.
- header class name `class="sorter-false"`.

If you aren't using my fork, then only the metadata and headers option methods above will work on the original version.

Comment: Another way is setting selectorSort option to empty string, so tablesorter will select nothing to make clickable inside the header.

~~~
$("table").tablesorter({
    selectorSort: ""
});
~~~

https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-selectorsort.html